# Are jenkins X and jenkins offering at google cloud marketplace same?

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, jenkins-x

I have worked with Jenkins X which is Jenkins running in Kubernetes cluster and I am seeing a new feature in the [Google Cloud marketplace here](https://marketplace.gcr.io/google/jenkins), which is offering Jenkins, are these same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Jenkins currently available in Google Cloud Marketplace is for the Jenkins Server.
Jenkins X is a new project, that is utilizing Kubernetes and ecosystem to provider a Kubernetes native equivalent to the Jenkins server, and provide horizontal scaling with no single point of failure and small footprint.